# solutions to these differential equations, intermediate steps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So say I have 2 equations of motion in Cartesian coordinates

$\ddot{x} = -\omega^2x$

and

$\ddot{y} = -\omega^2y.$

How would I get to the solutions:

$x = X\cos[\omega t + A]$

and $y=Y\cos[\omega t + B]?$

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What can you use, is $$\frac{d}{dt}(\dot x+iωx)=\ddot x+iω\dot x=iω(\dot x+iωx)$$ and its solution $$\dot x(t)+iωx(t)=e^{iωt}(\dot x(0)+iωx(0))$$ comprehensible and sufficient for a derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both equations can be solved the same way
$$\ddot{x} = -\omega^2x$$
$$\ddot{x} +\omega^2x=0$$
$$\ddot{x} -i^2\omega^2x=0$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$R^2 -i^2\omega^2=0 \implies R= \pm i \omega$$
Therefore the solution is :

$$x(t)=c_1cos (\omega t)+c_2 \sin( \omega t) \tag {1}$$

Note that
$$x = X\cos[\omega t + A]=X( \cos( \omega t)\cos (A)- \sin(\omega t)\sin(A))$$
$$x = X\cos (A) \cos( \omega t)- X\sin(A)\sin(\omega t)$$
Substitute in 1 ( I suppose X is a constant ):
$$c_1=X\cos (A)  \,\, ; c_2=- X\sin(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, but most of them amount to the same procedure: guess-and-check. The $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are the ones that get you to their own negatives after two differentiations, so they're a good candidate for the solution. Then you just need to take the $\omega$ into account, which you can do via the Chain Rule. These should be in your standard DE's toolbox. The $X$ and $Y$ amount to constants of integration, which are multiplicative in this case because of an underlying exponential structure.